# Is every homomorphism from $\langle(0,+\infty),\,\cdot\,,{}^{-1}\rangle$ into $\langle\{-1,1\},\,\cdot\,,{}^{-1}\rangle$ a constant valued function?

Tags: group-theory

Let $f$ be a homomorphism from $\langle(0,+\infty),\,\cdot\,,{}^{-1}\rangle$ into $\langle\{-1,1\},\,\cdot\,,{}^{-1}\rangle$. Must $f$ be a constant valued function, i.e. is $f(x)=1$ for all $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the only group homomorphism is $f(x)=1$. The reason why is very simple:

$$f(x)=f(\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x})=[f(\sqrt{x})]^2 \,.$$

Comment: $f(1)=[f(1)]^2\Rightarrow f(1)=1$

Comment: @Panu Well I proved that $f(x)=1$ for ALL $x$ ;)

Comment: hey N.S, how :-o

Comment: @Panu  $f(\sqrt(x))$ is $\pm 1$ because that is the range of $f$ ;)

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.